# How to make JS function stay activated as long as radio button is checked after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have two radio buttons, Yes and No. When Yes is clicked I display some content and hide it when No is clicked. The content is initially hidden, it is displayed only when Yes is clicked. They work just as intended, but the problem is that after I submit the form my content gets hidden even when the radio button Yes is clicked, I need a way to let it stay displayed after form submission if the user clicked Yes

Here are my radio buttons:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(n => n.HasCompanyVehicle, "Yes",  new { @class = "form-check-input ", @id="hasVehicle", onclick="showCompanyPolicyAndLicence();" })
```

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(n => n.HasCompanyVehicle, "No", new { @class = "form-check-input ", @id="noVehicle", onclick="showCompanyPolicyAndLicence();" })
```

And my function:

```
let showCompanyPolicyAndLicence = () => {
  let policyVehicleElem = document.querySelector("#policyVehicleElem");
  let buttonYes = document.querySelector("#hasVehicle").checked;
  let buttonNo = document.querySelector("#noVehicle").checked

  if (buttonYes == true) {
    policyVehicleElem.classList.remove("hide");
  } else if (buttonNo == true) {
    policyVehicleElem.classList.add("hide");
  }
};
```

The content to be hidden/displayed:

```
<span class="hide" id="policyVehicleElem">
    <span>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehiclePolicy, new { @class="form-label" })
    </span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehiclePolicy, new { @type = "file", @class="form-control form-control-sm" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehiclePolicy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <br />
    <span>
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LicenceExpiryDate, new { @class="form-label" })
    </span>
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LicenceExpiryDate, new { @type = "date", @class="form-control form-control-sm" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LicenceExpiryDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried executing `showCompanyPolicyAndLicence` on page load? Give it a try while handling the base case.

Comment: Yes I just tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Post more details of what you tried and what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my little knowledge of javascript, I suggest you try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var hasVehicle = document.getElementById(‘hasVehicle’);

var noVehicle = document.getElementById(‘noVehicle’);
if(hasVehicle.checked){
“Display your div”
}

if(noVehicle.checked){
“Hide your div”
}

// when the user submit the form you should redirect the page to the same url.
// your script goes here.

}
```

I hope this can fix your problem.

Comment: no need for jQuery here methinks